# Android - looping listView item using button for setText the TextView

Tags: android, listview

I've tried to find any tutorial from go*gle, but I'm still not yet find out what I need.

I have create a layout like this :

```
|------------------|
| 1.TextView       |
| * * * * *        |
|------------------|
| 2.TextView       |
| * * * * *        |
|------------------|
| 3.TextView       |
| * * * * *        |
|------------------|
|                  |
| Btn | TextView   |
```

but I want when the `button` pressed, it's collecting any item in each list, and setText to `TextView` like this :

```
|-------------------------|
| 1.TextView              |
| * * * * *               |
|-------------------------|
| 2.TextView              |
| * * *                   |
|-------------------------|
| 3.TextView              |
| * * * *                 |
|-------------------------|
|                         |
| Btn |"No : 1 - Star = 5"|
|      "No : 2 - Star = 3"|
|      "No : 3 - Star = 4"|
|-------------------------|
```

i just can setText one list with this code :

```
kirim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float tanya = adapter2.getItem(3).getRatingStar(); //getItem("list id")
            TextView Star = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.star);
            if (Star != null) {
                Star.setText("Star : "+tanya);
            }
        }
    });
```

I've tried to looping, but I can't figure out what should I do to get the id and value each list of ListView.

I've stuck at this code and not yet fix the error

```
kirim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float bintang = adapter2.getItem(3).getRatingStar();
            TextView Star = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.star);
            for(int i = 0; i<=adapter2.getCount(); i++)
                Star.setText("id 1" + i + "\nStar : "+bintang);
        }
    });
```

any idea or reference to let me read the flow of code please?

**EDIT**

`PertanyaanAdapter.java`

```js
class PertanyaanAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pertanyaan> {

    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    private List<Pertanyaan> movieList;

    PertanyaanAdapter(AppCompatActivity context, int resource, List<Pertanyaan> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity = context;
        this.movieList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public Pertanyaan getItem(int position) {
        return movieList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            //holder.ratingBar.getTag(position);
        }

        holder.ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(onRatingChangedListener(position));

        holder.ratingBar.setTag(position);
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(getItem(position).getRatingStar());
        holder.movieName.setText(getItem(position).getAsk());

        return convertView;
    }

    private RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener onRatingChangedListener(final int position) {
        return new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                Pertanyaan item = getItem(position);
                assert item != null;
                item.setRatingStar(v);
                Log.i("Adapter", "star: " + v);
            }
        };
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private RatingBar ratingBar;
        private TextView movieName;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rate_img);
            movieName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

`Pertanyaan.java`

```js
package flix.yudi.pertanyaan3;
public class Pertanyaan {

    private float ratingStar;
    private String ask;

    Pertanyaan(int ratingStar, String ask) {
        this.ratingStar = ratingStar;
        this.ask = ask;
    }

    float getRatingStar() {
        return ratingStar;
    }

    void setRatingStar(float ratingStar) {
        this.ratingStar = ratingStar;
    }

    public String getAsk() {
        return ask;
    }

}
```

Comment: post adapter code

Comment: @Divyesh I've edited with adapter code sir,

Comment: the loop is incorrect. Do something like this : 

        kirim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float bintang = adapter2.getItem(3).getRatingStar();
                TextView Star = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.star);
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i<=adapter2.getCount(); i++)
                    text.append("id 1" + i + "\nStar : "+bintang);
                Star.setText(text);
            }
        });

Comment: Why don't you loop through the list of data itselg. Because the list contains updated data.

Comment: @dondo : In loop you append the string to the variable of every item. and after loop exit, setText to the wholeString generated. SetText should not be in loop

Comment: @NigamPatro I don't know the code to loop thorugh ListView nor adapter, that's why i need help here, then i can't find the tutorial that can help me

Comment: @Vinodh so i just need to add `text.append` and `StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder()` to my code sir?

Comment: @dondo : u append each item one by one. And at the end setText.

Comment: @Vinodh actually, i need to send all value of `RatingBar` into server, but i don't know how to do yet, so i think this is the first step to know the value of each `ratingBar`, anyway your suggested code work's well, now i just need to know how to send any rating into `MySQL`, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `onClick()`

```
int size = adapter2.getCount();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    builder.append("No : " + (i + 1) + " - " + "Star = " + adapter2.getItem(i).getRatingStar() + "\n");
}
TextView Star = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.star);
star.setText(builder.toString());
```

Comment: i think i can't define int size constantly, because i get the `TextView` through API json, that's mean my list of listview may change, so i use `getCount`

Comment: it's work sir, but now i need a reference to send value into `MySQL`, do you have a piece code how to do? or i need to ask a new question? [this reference](http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-vote-rating-php-mysql.html) too hard to read the flow of how it's work,

Comment: That is the work from backend server. Which is not from Android. You can search for `PHP API` code instead. need to create own server to store that data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was setText was happening inside loop. So, using a StringBuilder preparing the text in loop using append() and after loop exit :

```
    kirim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView Star = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.star);
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i<=adapter2.getCount(); i++) {
                float bintang = adapter2.getItem(i).getRatingStar();
                text.append("id 1" + i + "\nStar : " + bintang);
            }
            Star.setText(text);
        }
    });
```

Now, to send data to MySQL ? if you mean database, you need to create a column named "Rating" and insert the row.

Comment: why should i named a column _Rating_? i'd created a column named _nilai_ , it's take effect?

Comment: No, you can create with whatever name you like. I just said as an example

Comment: but i don't know how it's work, i mean, can i put `insert class` inside looping button? like this [reference](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php)

Answer (score 0):

you will need one `linear layout` with vertical orientation and can add`textView` dynamically in that linear layout and show the `listView` data on the newly created `textView` by using `for loop`.
It will give you desired output as you want